# Unable to add picture to database

Tags: php

Why are my picture unable to be added into database, even if I created a blob datatype to store the file for variable `$picture`?

```
        //prepare and bind >>
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, email, gender, phonenum, address, ic_number, occupation, picture) VALUES 
                  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $stmt->bind_param("sssssssb", $name, $email, $gender, $phonenum, $address, $ic_number, $occupation, $picture);

          //                add into database >>
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
        $phonenum = $_POST['phonenum'];
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $ic_number = $_POST['ic_number'];
        $occupation = $_POST['occupation'];
        $picture = $_POST['picture'];

        echo "New records created successfully";
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->close();
        $conn->close();
    }
    ?>

</div>
<div class="right">
    <h3>Profile picture: </h3>
    <img id="output" style="width:150px;height:200px;"/>
    <br><input type="file" name="picture" placeholder="" onchange="loadFile(event)">


</div>
<!--            pictures-->
<script>
    var loadFile = function (event) {
        var output = document.getElementById('output');
        output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you outputting the success message "New records created successfully" before you are even executing the query? Why have you done nothing whatsoever yet to check whether the query was actually successful or not, and if not asked the database _what_ exactly went wrong - despite how to do that being easy enough to research/read up on?

Comment: @Carey That is an untrue statement.  Please read the first example in the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php then delete your comment.

Answer (score -2):

have you already checked the value $_POST['picture'] has data?

$_FILE holds data regarding attached files

Comment: This should rather be a comment.